# What is the difference between short and SHORT in c++?

Tags: c++, types

What is the difference between short and SHORT in c++? One datatype is all lower case and one is all caps. Is there a difference?

I think I get it. So is SHORT kind of like a class in Java?

Comment: short is all lowercase, but SHORT is all uppercase.

Comment: SHORT is not a datatype in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ does not have a `SHORT` data type. Win32's headers define one, but that's a platform-specific definition, not a part of C++.

As for the difference, Win32 guarantees that `SHORT` will be 16-bits in size. C++ makes few guarantees on the size of `short`.

`SHORT` had its greatest use early on in the life of Windows. It doesn't have much use now, since compilers have generally standardized `short` as 16-bits for most platforms.

Comment: And defining a type called `SHORT` is IMHO a bad idea. If it's always the same type as `short`, there's no reason not to just use the name `short`. If it can ever be something other than `short`, then `SHORT` is a bad name. (Something like `WORD` or `HALFWORD` might be a sensible name.)

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious difference is that `short` is actually part of C++, and `SHORT` is not. The all-caps version undoubtedly comes from some library or something on that order.